# Simulating heavy load in node/electron application

Tags: node.js, electron, child-process

I am looking to spawn some child processes in the background of an electron app to handle certain tasks. While I'm working on this, I'd like to see how it affects performance of the front end. Is there a function I can run that would simulate semi-heavy processing for a node process? The end goal here is to make sure that I am building an app that has a snappy UI even when there are some background processes that are under heavy load. I've messed this up in the past and want to get a head start on making sure I don't repeat mistakes.